# How to add a new key to a dictionary based on condition match of two existed dict key values in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm having a dictionary with boolean values as,

```
dict_prob = {'A': [True, False, True, False, True, True],
             'B': [False, False, True, False, True, False]}
```

Now i would like to create a key called **A_and_B** and add it to either new dict or the current dict as,

```
out_dict_con = {'A': [True, False, True, False, True, True],
                'B': [False, False, True, False, True, False],
                'A_and_B':[False,True,True,True,True,False] }
```

Basically the newly created key is a result of conjunction of A and B keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zip the two lists and compare in a list comprehension:

```
dict_prob = {'A': [True, False, True, False, True, True],
             'B': [False, False, True, False, True, False]}

dict_prob['A_and_B'] = [a == b for a,b in zip(dict_prob['A'], dict_prob['B'])]
```

`dict_prob` will be:

```
{'A': [True, False, True, False, True, True],
 'B': [False, False, True, False, True, False],
 'A_and_B': [False, True, True, True, True, False]}
```

Comment: `conjunction` means `and`, not `==`

Comment: @lenik look at the OP's desired output.

Comment: it's called `A_and_B` for a reason ?

Comment: *Again* @lenik look at the desired output.

Comment: @MarkMeyer you are correct. it's a kind of truth table.  and lenik i formally chose to give that name to key.

Answer (score 1):

you can add to python dict objects like so

```py
dict_prob['A_and_B'] = [not (a ^ b) for a,b in zip(dict_prob['A'], dict_prob['B']]
```

`^` is the XOR operator. Inverse of XOR is bidirectional.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
dict_prob = {'A': [True, False, True, False, True, True],
             'B': [False, False, True, False, True, False]}

dict_prob['A_and_B'] = [a and b for a,b in zip(dict_prob['A'], dict_prob['B']]
```

Comment: `a and b` is wrong here. They want `False` + `False` to be `True`

Comment: That is bidirectional. dont remember the operator